# Sparkfun edge message communication error

Tags: bootloader, serial-port, microcontroller

Recently I posted [this question in Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56607789/sparkfun-edge-message-wired-upgrade-unsuccessful-terminating-the-scrip). However, even after a bounty, nobody helped me.

Although I know that [cross-posting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu) is discourage, I come with good intentions and I think that this question could have a second opportunity here.

**The question:**

I am flashing a [Sparkfun edge board](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56607789/sparkfun-edge-message-wired-upgrade-unsuccessful-terminating-the-scrip) with the [SparkFun Serial Basic Breakout - CH340G](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/14050) using some of the examples that the IDE provides in the [oficial tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/using-sparkfun-edge-board-with-ambiq-apollo3-sdk/example-applications).

Although, it has properly worked many times, mainly for the examples *example1_edge_test* and *[AI on a microcontroller with TensorFlow Lite and SparkFun Edge](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/sparkfun-tensorflow)*, sometimes I get this message when flashing:

```
Connecting with Corvette over serial port /dev/ttyUSB0...
Sending Hello.
Received response for Hello
Received Unknown Message
msgType =  0x131
Length =  0x5800
['0x80', '0x6', '0xf0', '0xa5', '0x31', '0x1', '0x0', '0x58', '0x0', '0x3', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0xa0', '0xff', '0x4', '0x0', '0x2', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x7', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x1', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0xff', '0xa3', '0x2d', '0xff', '0xff', '0x5f', '0x5', '0x0', '0x1', '0x0', '0x0', '0x0', '0x3', '0x0', '0xf4', '0x49', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff', '0xff']
!!!Wired Upgrade Unsuccessful!!!....Terminating the script
```

It seems to happen when the script *AmbiqSuite-Rel2.0.0/AmbiqSuite-Rel2.0.0/boards/SparkFun_Edge_BSP/bsp/tools/uart_wired_update_sparkfun.py* establishes the connection with the board, which responses with a different (unknown) message that the one expected for an UART flashing: **AM_SECBOOT_WIRED_MSGTYPE_STATUS**.

I flash the board holding the button '14', pressing 'reset' and then executing 'make bootload', while holding '14'.

I've continued troubleshooting this issue and it has to be related to the communication timing, since when I change the baud rate (initially set to 921600), the error occurs more ofter.

Comment: Cross posting is [strongly discouraged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu), preferably if you want your question open here then it should be closed or deleted on the other site.

Comment: @Mokubai as the last answer of that thread enunciates: my intentions are good, and I just trying to best fit this question.